# Get form data for both POST and GET requests in Express

Tags: node.js, forms, post, express

I want to get the value of parameters for BOTH POST and GET requests in Express/Node.js. I know of methods that will explicitly get POST or GET data, but I would like something that works for both. Is this possible in one line of code?

```
express.all('/page', function(req, res) {
    var thing = req.body.thing; // only works for POST requests, not GET!
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `req.param(name, [defaultValue])`.

From [**Express** API Reference](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param)

```
Lookup is performed in the following order:

req.params
req.body
req.query
```

POST is `req.body`

GET is `req.query`

```
express.all('/page', function(req, res) {
    var thing = req.param('thing');
});
```

Alternatively you can use `req.body` and `req.query` directly.